# How to get all NFTs of a wallet address?

Tags: nft, api

I'm trying to retrieve all assets which are located at the specific wallet address, I queried through the docs but couldn't find anything suitable.

Can anybody provide me some help regarding this please?

What I'm trying to do is, let the user enter his wallet address and showcase him his NFTs in the web. If something like this is not doable please correct me.

Comment: Try pool.pm/address

Comment: @Distic im trying to do it through an official api, and i dont think its okay to fetch their html data and grawl it

Comment: Sorry I read it too fast

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using [cardano-wallet](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-wallet) package on a running node & then using this [endpoint](https://input-output-hk.github.io/cardano-wallet/api/edge/#tag/Assets) to list all assets on a wallet.

There are several ways to run `cardano-wallet` either a docker container or just installing the compiled binary on a running node which is what I did. You can find the binary [here](https://developers.cardano.org/docs/get-started/installing-cardano-wallet) as well as the documentation under the `note` section.

Answer (score 3):

Try the `/accounts/{stake_address}/addresses/assets` call using [Blockfrost](https://blockfrost.io/).

Answer (score 0):

There is a tutorial/examples on how to achieve it using blockfrost.

[Nft tutorial on Cardano](https://medium.com/@NickFan34818768/blockfrost-io-beginner-tutorial-cardano-blockchain-viewing-nft-part-1-c11b6bb8131a)